# Is Raspberry Pi fast enough for realtime video processing?

Tags: camera, video, image, real-time

I want to use Raspberry Pi 3 B+ on my RC airplane for a realtime image classification task. Airplane will be flying at an altitude ranged between 10-30 meters with a airspeed of 15m/s. What I need is to determine if any traffic cone involved in our camera view (I am planning to use Raspberry Pi Camera Module v1.3).

Is Raspberry Pi 3 B+ fast enough to perform this task successfully? If not, what might be the alternatives? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for "raspberry pi opencv detection" and you should find a bunch of things that demonstrate the capabilities.

Comment: As far as I have researched Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with openCV is barely capable of getting up to 0.9 fps. Are there any better optimizations which do not require an expensive external hardware?

Comment: This one seemed helpful to me:
https://qengineering.eu/deep-learning-with-raspberry-pi-and-alternatives.html